# Div not Centering in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, html, centering

I'm trying to get a div to be centered on the page. however WordPress isn't cooperating and doing it like it does in my testing HTML document. Any ideas?

HTML

```
<div class="propreq grid_4"><h2>Request a Proposal</h2></div>
```

CSS

```
.propreq {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #0e7bd0;
}
```

Comment: Could you try an even more specific selector? Maybe something like `.propreq h2 { text-align: center; }`?

Comment: I have that too, but that doesn't center the entire div

Comment: Do you have an example page that can be shown? I find it tricky to diagnose behaviour of an element in a CMS when the context (and its associated CSS) is missing.

Comment: The only page I have up right now with this is the home page, deserthersrating.com

Comment: Thanks, that actually helps immensely. (See my answer, now that I've posted one.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's because of a couple things. Try adding the styles below to your current definition (or changing them, if they're already there):

```
.propreq {
    display: block;
    float: none;
}
```

Before, `.propreq` had `display:inline, float:left` applied to it, making the styles you were applying to it ineffective. I hope this gives you what you were looking for! If not, let me know and I'll be happy to help further. Good luck!

Comment: This is what I needed Serlite! Thank you for your heal, I understand CSS a little better now because of you.

Comment: I'm glad I could help out! CSS is fun to play with, but there are a lot of little rules in it to remember.

Answer (score 0):

There could be Several reasons.

1st: Try examining the CSS using Developer's Tools (in Chrome/FireFox).
There could be another CSS rule which is OVER-RIDING your this one.

2nd: Try using

```
<div align="center" class="propreq grid_4"><h2>Request a Proposal</h2></div>
```

My best guess is, Another CSS-Rule is overtaking the Center Property.

```
.propreq {
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
background-color: #0e7bd0;
}
```

**TIP:** Do a quick search on "Examining using FireFox Developer Tools" | Check out for the <strike>`text-align: center;`</strike> in `.propreq` section.

Comment: The text-align:center is not striked out in Firefox Dev Tools. But the below solution works.